# I got errors when making typeahead in bootstrap 2.3

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-2

here is my code.

view : home.php

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="typeahead" autocomplete="off"  value="" />
```

controllers : site.php

```
public function index($query) {
    $this->db->select('cid,name');
       $this->db->from('contacts');
       $this->db->like('name',$query);
       $res = $this->db->get();
       $arr = array();
       foreach($res->result() as $row)
       {
          $arr[] = array('cid'=>$row->cid,'name'=>$row->name);
       }
       echo json_encode($arr);
        $this -> load -> view('home'); 
    }
```

javascript :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#search').typeahead({
   source: function(query,process){
      data = [];
      map = {};
      var source = [];

      $.getJSON('http://example.com/search/'+query, function(result) {
                  source = result;
                  $.each(source, function (i, dt) {
            map[dt.name] = dt;
            data.push(dt.name);
         });
         process(data);
         });
   },

   minLength:1,

   updater: function (item) {
      selectedItem = map[item].cid;
   }
});
});
</script>
```

I found this code from website, and always fail when I run it.
any answer from my problems? and can I use localhost?

and my errors :

> Severity: Warning Message: Missing argument 1 for Site::index()
>   Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: query

ps : I cannot post when I write site.com, so I change to example.com

thanks

Comment: Try removing the `value=""` from your HTML. It looks like when the page is loading, it is sending a blank query to the page, that's why you get the undefined variable error.

Comment: Controllers shouldn't communicate to database directly.

Comment: craine : still not working

Comment: fabiano : MVC right? yes, i edit it, but still not working..

the good news is i can see all the names in the bottom of error message.. [{..."cid":"12312314","name":"roger "...}]

what does that mean